# Si array retorna vacio, saltar al siguiente valor

Tags: php, laravel, api, webservice

Estoy trabajando con api de prestashop y en algunos casos me retorna que no existe nada, un array vacio, mi consulta es basicamente como hacer que si esto pasa se salte al siguiente valor a recorrer?

Aca lo que hago es traer todos los registros que tengo en una tabla, estos los paso por un foreach para ir recorriendo en el endpoint uno por uno y traer ciertos datos, pero como decia, me pasa que algunos de estos endpoint que consulto me retornan nada, vacios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para laravel que utilizo para consumir estos endpoint me retorna esto
`Undefined array key "id_customer"` en base a esto mi consulta es como validar si me retorna un array vacio o mas bien si el id_customer existe o no? de que forma puedo en base a eso pasar al siguiente id a recorrer, este es mi codigo en mi clase, cabe mencionar que todo esto lo tengo dentro de un una tarea jobs que ejecuto con schedule en Laravel

```
class syncCustomerFullAddressPrestashop implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        $GetDNICustomer = CustomerIdFromPrestashop::select('id_customer')->where('id_customer', '<=', '76584')->get();
        
        foreach($GetDNICustomer as $number) {
            try {
                $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://miweb.cl/', '12345678910', false);
                $xml = $webService->get([
                    'resource' => 'addresses',
                    'filter[id_customer]' => $number->id_customer,
                    'display' => 'full'
                ]);
                $resources = $xml->addresses->children();
                $json = json_encode($resources);
                $array = json_decode($json, true);
                //dd($array);                
                foreach($array as $resource) {
                    //($resource);
                    $resourceId = $resource['id_customer'];
                    $resourceDni = $resource['dni']? : 'Sin Rut';
                    $resourcePhone = $resource['phone'] ? : 'Sin numero';
                    //dd($resourcePhone);
                    $neworder = Customer::updateOrCreate(
                        ['prestashop_id' => $resourceId],
                        [
                            'dni' => $resourceDni,
                            'telephone' => $resourcePhone
                        ]
                    );
                }
                
            } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
                // Shows a message related to the error
                echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
                $neworder = ApiLog::Create(
                    [
                        'idendpoint' => $number->id_address_prestashop,
                        'endpoint' => 'Obteniendo direcciones completas, syncCustomerFromPrestashop',
                        'errordetails' => $ex->getMessage(),
                        'fechaerror' => now(),            
                    ]
                );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente forma:

Aqui actualizo de igual forma los 2 campos, de no existir le indico que precisamente no existen direcciones, cosa que al momento de existir seran agregadas...

```
if( sizeof($array) == 0 ){
                   //"Empty Array";
                   $neworder = Customer::updateOrCreate(
                    ['prestashop_id' => $number->id_customer,],
                    [
                        'dni' => 'No existe direccion',
                        'telephone' => 'No existe direccion'
                    ]
                );
                }
                else{
                    //dd("Non-Empty Array");
                    foreach($array as $resource) {
                        //dd($resource);
                        $resourceId = $resource['id_customer'];
                        $resourceDni = $resource['dni']? : 'Sin Rut';
                        $resourcePhone = $resource['phone'] ? : 'Sin numero';
                        //dd($resourcePhone);
                        $neworder = Customer::updateOrCreate(
                            ['prestashop_id' => $resourceId],
                            [
                                'dni' => $resourceDni,
                                'telephone' => $resourcePhone
                            ]
                        );
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
foreach($GetDNICustomer as $number) {
 // validamos que no exista el id costumer
 // y saltamos a la siguiente iteracion
 if(!isset($number->id_customer)){ continue; }

  try {
  //resto del codigo
```